# How can I convert the music/effects volume value numbers to some reasonable units like 0-100?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I have audio mixer and two ui sliders.
I'm using the ui sliders to change the music/effects volumes.

The volumes are working fine the problem is when displaying the current volume value number it's showing it in float units. And I want it to be display in int units from 0 to 100.

In each slider in the inspector i set the min value to 0 and maximum value to 1:

[image: sliders]

While the game is running and when I'm changing the slider/s i display the current volume value in a Text (In the hierarchy in the screenshot it's MusicText and EffectsText under Slider and Slider (1))

[image: Volumes]

You can see in the second screenshot in the left game view window the current volume value number is 0.8258139

And if I will move the slider to the most right it will be value 1 in the end and to the most left it will be 0.
But I want the user to see the values from 0 to 100. I'm not sure but I think the most common sense is to display the volume units from 0 to 100 and not some long float values.

How can i convert the volume units to 0-100 ?

This script is attached to the AudioPanel in the Hierarchy and I'm using musicText and effectsText to display the volume values numbers:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider musicVolume;
    public Slider effectsVolume;
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
    public Text musicText;
    public Text effectsText;

    private void Start()
    {
        SetMusicVolume();
        SetEffectsVolume();
    }

    public void SetMusicVolume()
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("musicVol", Mathf.Log10(musicVolume.value <= 0 ? 0.001f : musicVolume.value) * 40f);
        musicText.text = musicVolume.value.ToString();
    }

    public void SetEffectsVolume()
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("effectsVol", Mathf.Log10(effectsVolume.value <= 0 ? 0.001f : effectsVolume.value) * 40f);
        effectsText.text = effectsVolume.value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to make the display more readable and intuitive you could multiply your 0.0-1.0 value by 100 and round it to remove the decimal places. I'd do something like this:

```
public void SetMusicVolume()
{
    audioMixer.SetFloat("musicVol", Mathf.Log10(musicVolume.value <= 0 ? 0.001f : musicVolume.value) * 40f);
    musicText.text = Math.Round(musicVolume.value * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
}
```